# Trigger to insert one record to new rows from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a small app that inserts data into the database.

I have a something like this

`dbo.system.table1(col1, col2, col3)` and `table2(col1)` (`table2.col1` is just one single row).

What I want to do is `insert the table2.col1 into table1.col3` when a new order is made.

Also the `table2.col1` updates twice a day, so every time a new order is made with `table1` I need to keep the old `table1.col3` changes.

I've tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TR_CHANGES
ON dbo.SYSTEM 
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE table1
    SET table1.col3 = (SELECT col1 
                       FROM table2
                       WHERE table1.col3 = table2.col1)
```

But it ends updating col3 for all rows.

Comment: You need to make use of the `inserted` table to only update the rows that where changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `Inserted` pseudo table into your statement, to find the rows that were actually updated - and I would recommend using proper `JOIN` syntax instead of those nested subqueries - seems a lot easier to read and understand for me.

So try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TR_CHANGES
ON dbo.SYSTEM 
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE t1
    SET col3 = t2.col1
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col3 = t2.col1
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON t1.primarykeycol = i.primarykeycol
```

You need to replace the `.primarykeycol` for the `Inserted` and `t1` tables with the **actual** primary key column for your table - this is needed to link the `Inserted` rows with the actual data table

Comment: I've made a small mistake, SYSTEM is the database, should i replace `ON dbo.table1 or table2`?

Comment: Whichever table you're using for the insert, which should trigger this update...... you haven't been clear enough in your question for me to decide that ....

Comment: I tried that, but the t1.col3 remains null, i just need that t2.col1 fills t1.col3 after every insert, what i've noticed is that t1 has 3 primary keys, does it affect in some what?

Comment: What I did was replace i.primarykeycol=t1.primarykeycol